# What is the best way to host few web-apps for FREE?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, openshift

I figured out a few options:

1. On Amazon; which gives us one micro instance ( 600 MB RAM ) free for 1 year and RDS for 2 months.
2. Google App Engine. But this puts limitations on what all I can use in my code. So, my code is very much dependant on hosting provider.
3. RedHat OpenShift which is giving 3 micro instances free for life time. Looks like the best bet. Only problem is this is newest entrant.

Any other options available or any feedback on above 3 choices?

Comment: For Java apps see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750266/cloud-platforms-where-simple-java-web-application-can-be-deployed-for-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few alternatives.  I like to use [appfog](http://appfog.com/), as it supports a wide variety of languages and allows up to ten free micro apps.  Appfog also lets you use your own domain via A or cname, a feature that some of the others don't offer for free.  Most PaaS (platform as a service) providers offer free plans, such as [dotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/), [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) and [pagodabox](https://pagodabox.com/)(php only).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [dotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) and [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I'm most familiar with AppEngine which I am pretty happy with so far, though as you mention it will be harder to migrate an app from there.

I think it's important to make sure that the host supports your chosen language very well.

I'd advise you to look beyond the free portion of the services. Unless you have a very unique set of needs, you will pretty quickly need to move beyond what is offered by the free portion of the various services.